# Jenkins couldn't open IOS simulator

Tags: ios, jenkins, ios-simulator, appium

I have a project setuped in jenkins that supposed to open IOS simulator during the run but jenkins couldn't open the simulator.

Jenkins run in jenkins user.

Below is what the project use:
 - Java maven based project
 - Runs appium server
 - appium start IOS simulator --  this step fail with the below error

```
[XCUITest] Error: Command 'osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to count processes whose bundle identifier is "com.apple.iphonesimulator"'' exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/teen_process.js:92:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:897:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
 { Error: Command 'osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to count processes whose bundle identifier is "com.apple.iphonesimulator"'' exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (../../lib/teen_process.js:92:19)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:897:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
  stdout: '',
  stderr: '36:106: execution error: An error of type -610 has occurred. (-610)\n',
  code: 1 }
```

I tried adding jenkins user to developer group and enable DevToolsSecurity but it didn't work.

Comment: Is your Jenkins configured as a headless user? No password, bash environment etc?

Comment: Looks like we're having the same (or at least very similar) problem. I'll share the thread that I posted in Appium Discuss: https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-tests-via-jenkins-simulator-not-booting-error-command-osascript-e-tell-application-system-events-to-count-processes-whose-bundle-identifier-is-com-apple-iphonesimulator/19038

Comment: @KamilSzostakowski its running as deamon. 
the jenkins user is sudoer, and it does have the need environment variables

Answer (score 0):

If you run Jenkins as a daemon it won't be able to run GUI application. You have to configure it as a Launch Agent or use a local slave.

Here you can find a [complete tutorial](https://medium.com/@ved.pandey/setting-up-jenkins-on-mac-osx-50d8fe16df9f).

> By default Jenkins runs as a daemon. A daemon is a non interactive background process which runs as part of the overall system and is not tied to a specific user. A daemon can’t interact with GUI.
>
> A big part of CI is running simulators and other GUI applications, so we’ll need another option. To fix this, you can change Jenkins to run as a Launch Agent. A launch agent runs in the background on behalf of a user.

Comment: Thanks, will try it.